# GWT MVP Problem

Tags: gwt, gwt-mvp

I am a newbie to GWT .I am trying to implement my code using MVP.

So following a tutorial

1. I have created a `View`,
2. I have created a `Presenter`,
3. I created a `Display` interface inside the presenter,
4. My view implements my `Presenter.Display` interface.

Just for the proof of concept I created a `Button` in the View. In my presenter I wrote the `ClickHandler`.
Now when I debug this project I can see my view but the functionality I have assigned in my presenter is not implemented. In other words, the View and the Presenter are not binded together.

How do I bind them? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: It will be much easier to spot the problem if you gave us some code. Also, it may help to step through with a debugger and see what gets called in what order.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using GIN in your project?
Can you post your code of view and presenter and where you are binding them.
You cam bind view and presenter using:

```
 bindPresenter(MyPresenter.class, MyPresenter.Display.class, MyView.class);
```

Have you added above code in your Presenter module?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you create the view and the presenter? When creating them, pass the view to the presenter for example as an argument in the Presenters constructor. Like this

```
MyView v = MyView();
Mypresenter p = MyPresenter(v);
```

then in MyPresenter...

```
PView view = Display.View; // the display/interface where View is defined.
MyPresenter(Displat view) {
    this.view = v
    bind();
}

bind() {
    view.getThis,GetThat.addClickHandler(...) and so on...
}
```

Hope this helps.